# Netty frame decoder for protocol with variable lines per request?

Tags: netty

I'm new to Netty and I'm trying to build a simple SMTP server. The problem that I've run into is that most SMTP server commands are composed of a single line that is easily read in the messageReceived() method. However, after receiving a number of one line commands from the client, the "data" portion of the email can contain any number of lines. This works fine with short emails but longer emails can result in only partial data. My understanding is that this is due to the fact that I don't have any frame decoders in the pipeline right now.

The problem I have is that single line commands are delimited with a linefeed but the "data" section consists of any number lines terminated with a "." on its own line.

Is it possible to create a frame decoder that works for both single line commands and multi-line requests terminated with a special character sequence?

Thanks!

Dustin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need one decoder to do both jobs. You can create two decoders, one for the headers and one for the data portion. Once you have completed the header portion, get a reference to the pipeline, remove the "header decoder"  and add the "data decoder". Once that's complete, reset the pipeline to the original config and continue.

Comment: I initially configure the pipeline in the handler that is shared by all incoming requests. If I "get a reference to the pipeline" while processing a request, is this pipeline specific to that request (meaning that I can add/remove decoders without affecting other requests)?

Comment: You bet!  Isn't. Isn't netty great!

Answer (score 1):

Apache James uses Netty for SMTP so you might want to check out how they do it: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/james/server/trunk/protocols-smtp/src/main/java/org/apache/james/smtpserver/netty/